# Can we use MailMessage API in Mailable class?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In notification email, we can use some API to write the mail rapidly using methods like greeting(), line() etc..

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#mail-notifications

Can we use the same API in Mailable class?

Thanks

Comment: It going to be a pull request.

Answer (score 2):

No. The `Mailable` class does not implement the same methods as the `MailMessage` class.

You can use the `MailMessage` class outside of notifications, if you need to, but you'll have to send the mail object yourself.

```
$message = (new \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage())
    ->to(/* */)
    ->subject(/* */)
    ->line(/* */)
    ->action(/* */)
    ->line(/* */);

// most of this code is copied from \Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel
Mail::send($message->view, $message->data(), function ($m) use ($message) {
    if (!empty($message->from)) {
        $m->from($message->from[0], isset($message->from[1]) ? $message->from[1] : null);
    }

    $m->to($message->to);

    if ($message->cc) {
        $m->cc($message->cc);
    }

    if (!empty($message->replyTo)) {
        $m->replyTo($message->replyTo[0], isset($message->replyTo[1]) ? $message->replyTo[1] : null);
    }

    $m->subject($message->subject ?: 'Default Subject');

    foreach ($message->attachments as $attachment) {
        $m->attach($attachment['file'], $attachment['options']);
    }

    foreach ($message->rawAttachments as $attachment) {
        $m->attachData($attachment['data'], $attachment['name'], $attachment['options']);
    }

    if (!is_null($message->priority)) {
        $m->setPriority($message->priority);
    }
});
```

NB: this is untested, but I think it should work.

Comment: And is there any way to send mail directly without using mailable class?

Comment: @ParthVora Updated my answer.

Comment: I suppose this only works if you set a view to the message. When using the default markdown template, it doesn't work as expected. It throws an `InvalidArgumentException` with the message *Invalid view.* for `$message->view` param.

Comment: @GustavoStraube This worked in 5.3. 5.4 introduced the support for markdown views, so the view logic changed a little bit and you'd get that error. You can take a look at the [5.4 MailChannel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php) to see how they deal with the views.

Comment: Thanks, @patricus! I'm actually was able to write a similar solution based on your answer and looking at the code for the current version.